# Xamarin Authentication Version control operation failed when connecting to github

Tags: windows, github, xamarin, keychain

I'm trying to publish some code to my GitHub repository from within Xamarin Studio 5.1

When I first did the publish it prompted me for my Username and Password which I entered but I made a type in my password.
Now whenever I try to publish I get the error:

```
NGit.Errors.TransportException: https://github.com:443/xxx/yyy: not authorized
   at NGit.Api.FetchCommand.Call()
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Git.GitRepository.OnPublish(String serverPath, FilePath localPath, FilePath[] files, String message, IProgressMonitor monitor)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Repository.Publish(String serverPath, FilePath localPath, FilePath[] files, String message, IProgressMonitor monitor)
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.PublishWorker.Run()
   at MonoDevelop.VersionControl.Task.BackgroundWorker(Object state)
```

And I don't get prompted to re-enter my password.

I've read from here about deleting the KeyChain:
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2657/version-control-operation-failed-https-git-not-authorized

I thought the equivalent of the KeyChain app was the Windows Credentials Manager and I've deleted a few things from there that look as though they may be relevant and restarted Xamarin but I'm still not getting prompted for my password.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't deleted the correct credentials from the Windows Credential Manager.
Under the Windows Credentials I found the github credential.  Removed that and then tried the publish again.  I now get prompted for the password details again.